# Efficiently selecting row of Pandas Dataframe which contains digit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to select rows which contains digits in dataframe.
I am using this.

```
s = set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
df["text"].apply(lambda x:any(i in list(x) for i in s))
```

Trying to get separate the sentences with digits.

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected output?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `\d` for match digit:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['text1','text','random 4.88 text']})

m = df["text"].str.contains(r'\d')
print (m)
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: text, dtype: bool
```

For filtering:

```
df1 = df[df["text"].str.contains(r'\d')]
```

Answer (score 1):

copied from [isnumeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html)

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series(['one', 'one1', '1', ''])
s1.str.isnumeric()
```

returns

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

to select the elements:

```
s1[s1.str.isnumeric()]
```